# incorrect fill when plot is in stepline slyle

Tags: plot, pine-script, fill, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Weeks_OC", shorttitle="Weeks_OC", overlay=true)

w_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on) 

w_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", open,barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on) 
 


p1=plot(w_open,title='w_open', color = w_close >= w_open ? color.blue : color.red, style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=3)
p2=plot(w_close,title='w_close',color = w_close >= w_open ? color.blue : color.red, style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=3)


fill(plot1=p1, plot2=p2, color = w_close >= w_open ? color.blue : color.red)
```

[image: screenshot]

PineScript v5

Simple indicator that shows open-close area of a week.
Fill function seems works incorrectly when given plot is in stepline slyle

Comment: What's wrong? Is it the gaps on two sides?

Comment: @vitruvius yes, it must be completely filled rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have Extended hours enabled. Please switch it to Regular Trading Hours.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Weeks_OC", shorttitle="Weeks_OC", overlay=true)

var int     transp = input.int(50, 'Transparency', 0, 100)

var color   c_blue = color.new(color.blue, transp)
var color   c_red  = color.new(color.red,  transp)

[w_open,w_close] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', [open,close], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on) 

newWeek = ta.change(weekofyear)

mycolor = newWeek ? na : w_close >= w_open ? c_blue : c_red

p1 = plot(w_open,  'w_open',  mycolor)
p2 = plot(w_close, 'w_close', mycolor)

fill(p1, p2, mycolor)
```

Which yields

[image]